# how to retrieve keys from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array like below:

```
$permis =array(
 'employee' => array(
     'myprofile' => array(
        'default' => '1', 'personal' => '0', 'job' => '0', 'leave' => '0', 'permission' => '0', 'bonus & commision' => '0', 'document' => '0', 'emergency contact' => '0', 'benifits' => '0'
        )
    )
);
```

I want to get only the key values are stored in a table like below:

```
employee  myprofile default

employee  myprofile personal

employee myprofile  job

employee myprofile leave
```

like etc.

How to get this using foreach in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<?php

    $permis =array(
     'employee' => array(
         'myprofile' => array(
            'default' => '1', 'personal' => '0', 'job' => '0', 'leave' => '0', 'permission' => '0', 'bonus & commision' => '0', 'document' => '0', 'emergency contact' => '0', 'benifits' => '0'
            )
        )
    );


    foreach($permis as $key => $myprofile){

        $loop1 = $key;
        foreach($myprofile as $key => $profile){
            $loop2 = implode(" ",array_keys($myprofile));
            foreach($profile as $key => $data){
                echo $loop1."    ".$loop2."    ".$key."<br />";
            }
        }

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: @nisanth if this code works for you then mark it accepted. So, it will improvement for community.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. if i want to get the values of myprofile array also means what can i change for example :            employee  myprofile default     1 

employee  myprofile personal     0  etc

Comment: Yes, You can extend string by adding `$data` in it.

Comment: use this  `echo $loop1."    ".$loop2."    ".$key." ".$data."<br />";`

Comment: If i add more arrays means i want to change the coding ah  ? ex myprofile1 , myprofile 2, myprofile 3

Comment: how to do that if multiple array means.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93235/discussion-between-nisanth-and-sandeepsure).

Comment: Check `array_walk()` for your  solution. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Answer (score 0):

If your array structure is static, i.e. always as shown, the following will work:

```
foreach ($permis as $employee => $permit) {
  foreach ($permit as $profile => data) {
    foreach ($data as $item => $value) {
      $row = array($employee, $profile, $item);

      // Do what you like with $row here

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help. but while i am try your code it will show like below:   Array ( [0] => employee [1] => myprofile [2] => default ) Array ( [0] => employee [1] => myprofile [2] => personal ) Array ( [0] => employee [1] => myprofile [2] => job ) Array ( [0] => employee [1] => myprofile [2] => leave ) Array ( [0] => employee [1] => myprofile [2] => permission )  like this. am using print_r($row). how to solve this

Comment: If you read those lines, you'll see they are what you asked for in you questions. Try reading the source of the output so line breaks are kept - otherwise, the output of `print_r` is not readable very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($permis as $employee){
     foreach($employee as  $profile){
           $default = $profile['default'];
           //add here all other values;
     }
```

}

But if you have only one profile for each employee you could do like this:

```
foreach ($permis as $employee){
  $default = $employee['myprofile']['default'];
```

}

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach loop like:

```
$array = [1,2,3,4];
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    echo 'key=' . $key . '<br/>';
    echo 'value=' . $value. '<br/>';
}
```